# SSDT, SSDT-BI confusion in backwards compatibility for different SQL version

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

After extensively searching over google about SSDT and SSDT-BI for different SQL Server versions, I would like someone to pin-point differences and clear my messed up thoughts !

**Aim:** To *upgrade* SSIS packages from sql server-2012 to sql server-2014.

- Originally build from:  build on SSDT-BI 2010 Shell(Integrated) which were deployed on SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition.

Now I need to deploy them on SQL Server 2014 Developer edition (for test purpose).

- I have successfully installed SSDT-BI 2013 Shell(Integrated) and SSDT 2015 Shell(Integrated).

**Problem:**

1. When I open my package in 2013, it prompts for Package Upgrade wizard(which later on fails to upgrade), **but 2015 doesn't give any such prompt (why?)**. It simply opens. I understand that this is because, we can choose `Deployment Target Version` in 2015 and 'package upgrade' is done in 2015 when actually deploying at any version. So am I right?
2. I thought SSDT 2015 was meant to be only for SQL Server 2016 and not earlier versions. So, am I right to assume that SSDT 2013 can be used with SQL 2012 ?
3. 2015 Shell(Integrated) is SSDT or SSDT-BI? What's the difference in it?

**What I understand:**

1. - SQL 2012 : SSDT-BI 2010 Shell Integrated
   - SQL 2014 : SSDT-BI 2013 Shell Integrated
   - SQL 2016 : SSDT 2015 Shell Integrated
2. Backwards compatibility of SQL 2016. ie Packages created in SSDT 2015 can be deployed on 2016,2014,2012.

I would appreciate someone answering point by point and clear the confusion. Definitely, there is some pointers, which I don't understand fully.

Cheers.

ps: [This blog](https://sqlstudies.com/2017/08/23/changing-the-version-of-an-ssis-package/) was helpful while figuring things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First and Second problem**

If you check this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/installing-integration-services-versions-side-by-side), then you will see that SSDT 2015 can be used with SQL Server 2012+, but SSDT 2013 is only used with SQL Server 2014

**Third problem**

If you refer to this [Artcile](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9054/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-versions-and-tools/):

In SSIS 2012 , 2013:

> Because of confusion with the database tools in Visual Studio (also called SSDT), the templates were renamed to SQL Server Data Tools for Business Intelligence (SSDT-BI).

In SSIS 2015 :

> Database tools and business intelligence tools are combined into one single product: SSDT. Separate download.

You can also refer to this link for additional info:

- [Previous releases of SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT and SSDT-BI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi)

Comment: Exactly the links I was looking for. Thanks for pointing them.