# SSIS Extension for Visual Studio 2022

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools, visual-studio-2022

I have downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2022. Then after click on modify

[image: to add SSDT]

[image: here you can see]

Now, I want to create SSIS package, for this I have started VS22 and in **"manage extensions"** when I try to find Microsoft SSIS, I am unable to find.

For this, I have downloaded SSIS from market place:

- [SQL Server Integration Services Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects)

but when I try to install this it throws below error:

[image]

Answer (score 84, accepted):

#### Update 5 Jun. 2023 - General Availability (GA) release

Microsoft released Version 1.0 (General Availability (GA) release) of the SQL Server Integration Services extension for Visual Studio 2022.

#### Update 24 Nov. 2022 - Public preview released

Microsoft added a public preview of the [SQL Server Integration Services Projects 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.MicrosoftDataToolsIntegrationServices) to the Visual Studio marketplace, which is *tested against Visual Studio 2022 17.4*

[image]

*[Read the announcement](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/public-preview-of-ssis-projects-for-vs-2022/ba-p/3683146)*

#### Update 19 Sep. 2022

Microsoft Data Platform MVP [Andy Leonard stated that](https://andyleonard.blog/2022/08/updated-ssis-extension-v4-1-2-includes-support-for-visual-studio-2022/) *"I communicated with the Microsoft SSIS Team. They shared they are targeting a preview of VS2022 Integration Services Extension for the end of CY22"*.

[image]

---

#### Update 12 Jul. 2022

Microsoft [announced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/analysis-services-and-reporting-services-extensions-for-visual-studio-2022-are-here/) the support for Visual Studio 2022 via the [Microsoft Analysis Services Projects 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects2022) extension.

---

#### Update 01 Jul. 2022

Microsoft [mentioned](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects&ssr=false#qna) that Visual Studio 2022 support is one of the major items they are working on, and it will be released **before the end of the year**.

[image]

---

#### Update 23 Jun. 2022

Microsoft released SSIS 4.0, adding support to SQL Server 2022, but still, **this version does not support Visual Studio 2022.**

[image]

In addition, the support of Visual Studio 2022 is added as a **common issue**

[image]

---

#### Update 23 Feb. 2022

Microsoft released SSIS 3.16, where the support of Visual Studio 2022 is removed from the SSIS Installer (Bug fixed).

[image]

---

#### Initial Answer - 16 Feb. 2022

Microsoft SQL Server business intelligence extensions **are still unavailable for Visual Studio 2022.**

Many people are still confused about the difference between SQL Server Data Tools used to create SQL databases projects and the business intelligence suite:

- [SSDT, SSDT-BI confusion in backwards compatibility for different SQL version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984800/ssdt-ssdt-bi-confusion-in-backwards-compatibility-for-different-sql-version/48988446#48988446)

Using Visual Studio 2022, only the SQL Server Data Tools required to create database projects are currently available. As mentioned in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15):

> The core SSDT functionality to create database projects has remained integral to Visual Studio. The extensions for Analysis Services, Integration Services, and Reporting Services projects are currently unavailable for Visual Studio 2022.

You can note that in the Visual Studio marketplace, only Visual Studio 2019 is mentioned:

[image]

Comment: Check also this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.MicrosoftDataToolsIntegrationServices

Comment: seems like it still doesn't support arm64 :\

Comment: Can the answer here be cleaned up to remove all the no-longer relevant information? It's hard to read and discern which bits, if any, are useful. Old information should be removed entirely from the post when superseding updates are made, to keep the post clean and clear. That old information is always visible in the revision history page.

Answer (score 6):

As Microsoft support [commented on 2022-02-08](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects&ssr=false#qna):

> Supporting VS2022 is on our radar, but there's no exact ETA now.

Answer (score 2):

As per the link June/22/22:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects&ssr=false#qna

[image]

VS2022 support for SSIS is before the end of this year.